# L-BFGS converging with R optim, but not with RcppEnsmallen

Tags: r, optimization, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am using the below functions to call lbfgs using RcppEnsmallen to maximize a function defined by computeQval() :

```
double Qfunc::EvaluateWithGradient(const arma::mat& x, arma::mat& g)
{
  // Initialize the function value and gradient vector
  
  Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXd> eigen_X(x.memptr(), x.n_rows, x.n_cols);

  Eigen::VectorXd x_vec = eigen_X.col(0);
  double Q = 0.0;
  std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> inputWeightArray = listMat(inputWeightArrayList);
  Eigen::MatrixXd inputWeightArray_st = inputWeightArray[curr_state];
  Eigen::MatrixXd inputWeightArray_st_clone(inputWeightArray_st);
  inputWeightArray_st_clone.col(next_state) = x_vec;
  
  //Compute function value for input x_vec
  Q = computeQval(x_vec);
  if(std::isinf(Q))
  {
    Q = -1000000.0;
  }
  //Compute the gradient for input x_vec
  Eigen::VectorXd grad = derivateQfunc(x_vec);
  Eigen::MatrixXd y = Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd>(grad.data(), grad.size(), 1);
  g = arma::mat(y.data(), y.rows(), y.cols(), false, false);
  
  
  // Return the function value as a numeric scalar
  return (-Q);
}
```

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat optimizeQfunc_arma(Rcpp::NumericVector x, Rcpp::List& inputWeightArrayList, 
                             const Rcpp::DataFrame& binned_spiketrain, 
                             Rcpp::List& log_xi, 
                             Rcpp::NumericMatrix log_gamma, 
                             Rcpp::NumericMatrix probMatrix,
                             int curr_state, int next_state, int n_observations,int n_states)
{
    
    Eigen::VectorXd eigen_x = (as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> >(x));
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> inputWeightArray = listMat(inputWeightArrayList);
    std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd> eigen_log_xi = listMat(log_xi);
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> eigen_ProbMatrix(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> >(probMatrix));
    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> eigen_log_gamma(as<Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> >(log_gamma));

    Qfunc q(inputWeightArrayList, 
                            eigen_ProbMatrix,
                            binned_spiketrain, 
                            eigen_log_xi, 
                            eigen_log_gamma,
                            curr_state, next_state,n_observations,  n_states);

    Rcout << q.derivateQfunc(eigen_x) << std::endl;
    Rcout << q.computeQval(eigen_x) << std::endl;                        

    arma::vec vec_data = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(x);
    arma::mat x_mat = vec_data;

    ens::L_BFGS optimizer;
       
    optimizer.Optimize(q, x_mat);

    return x_mat;
}
```

RcppEnsmallen optimizer evaluated the function and gradient, but does not do any update and returns the same initial values:

```
Optimization Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Initial coordinates: 
 2.3434  0.0127 -4.7116  ... -4.7017

Final coordinates: 
 2.3434  0.0127 -4.7116  ... -4.7017
iter          loss          loss change   |gradient|    total time    

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Version:
ensmallen:                    2.19.1 (Eight Ball Deluxe)
armadillo:                    12.6.4 (Cortisol Retox)

Function:
Coordinates rows:             12
Coordinates columns:          1

Loss:
Initial                       92.452
Final                         92.452
Change                        0.000

Optimizer:
Iterations:                   0 (No steps taken! Did the optimization fail?)
Evaluate calls:               51
Gradient calls:               51
Time (in seconds):            14.024
```

However, R optim converges to a local minima:

```
Browse[4]> res<-optim(par = inputWeightArray[,n,m], Qfunc,derivateQfunc, method="L-BFGS-B",
+            inputWeightArray,binned_spiketrain,log_xi,log_gamma,curr_state=1,next_state=2,control = list(fnscale=-1))
Browse[4]> res
$par
 [1]   4.8103809   0.9332788  -3.4781151  -7.8554820   9.4818493  10.0474750 -13.2142134  10.3501064   5.7930575
[10]  10.4973834   8.7745170  -7.5360977

$value
[1] -83.6604

$counts
function gradient 
      17       17 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

To test the if the function and gradient are computed correctly in Rcpp, I used the Rcpp functions QTest and derivTest to call computeQval and derivateQfunc respectively, which was used with RcppEnsmallen:

```
Browse[4]> res<-optim(par = inputWeightArray[,n,m],QTest,derivTest, method="L-BFGS-B",
+           inputWeightArray=inputWeightArrayList,binned_spiketrain=binned_spiketrain,probMatrix=probMatrix,log_xi=log_xi,log_gamma=log_gamma,curr_state=0,next_state=1,n_observations=n_observations,n_states=n_states,control = list(fnscale=-1))
Browse[4]> res
$par
 [1]   4.8103809   0.9332788  -3.4781151  -7.8554820   9.4818493  10.0474750 -13.2142134  10.3501064   5.7930575
[10]  10.4973834   8.7745170  -7.5360977

$value
[1] -83.6604

$counts
function gradient 
      17       17 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH""
```

I don't understand why R optim is able to find a minima, whereas RcppEnsmallen is mostly searching around the intial parameter values (checked with print statements during optimization) ? Is it due to difference in the implementation of lbfgs in both libraries or am I doing some wrong configuration with RcppEnsmallen?

Comment: 1. Please avoid mixing `armadillo` and `eigen` code inside the optimization function, 2. `R` is using `"L-BFGS-B"` and `Ensmallen` is using "L-BFGS"`, 3. I think the parameters are not being updated due to the data being supplied 4. Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MWE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to explore?